# Angular check and uncheck boxes from data

Tags: angular

I have a form with multiple checkboxes. I want to check the boxes when the user has a role or a team (they can have multiple roles/teams). I also want to uncheck the boxes (remove role/team) and send the removed roles.

The data from nodejs is like this:

```
{
    "User": {
        "to_jsonb": {
            "roles": [
                {
                    "role_id": 1,
                    "role_name": "Admin"
                },
                {
                    "role_id": 2,
                    "role_name": "VIP"
                },
                {
                    "role_id": 1,
                    "role_name": "Moderator"
                },
                {
                    "role_id": 2,
                    "role_name": "Member"
                }
            ],
            "teams": [
                {
                    "team_id": 1,
                    "team_name": "Team 1"
                },
                {
                    "team_id": 2,
                    "team_name": "Team 2"
                },
                {
                    "team_id": 1,
                    "team_name": "Team 3"
                },
                {
                    "team_id": 2,
                    "team_name": "Team 4"
                }
            ],
            "username": "Name",
            "id": 1
            
        }
    }
}
```

I want to make the checkboxes (checked) if the user's data contains any of the above (role/Team)

In HTML

```
   <mat-checkbox [checked]="isAdmin" name="Admin" value="1" (change)="roleChecked($event)" class="checkbox-margin-left">Admin
   </mat-checkbox>
```

and in profile.ts :

```
if (this.user.role.some(e => e.role_name === 'Admin')) {
    this.isAdmin= true;
  }
```

Now, this works fine, but I have about 10 teams and it doesn't look optimal.

However, the biggest issue I am facing is when a box is unchecked. What I am currently doing is I have created an interface e.g:

```
export interface Roles {
    role_id: number;
    role_name: string;
}
```

and I am removing the roles like this:

```
 selectedRole : {
    role_id: number,
    role_name: string
  } [] = [];
      
roleChecked(event){
        if(event.checked){
          let roleData = {} as Roles;
          roleData.role_id = event.source.value
          roleData.role_name = event.source.name
          this.selectedRole .push(roleData);
    
          console.log(this.selectedRole );
        } else if (!event.checked){
          this.selectedRole = this.selectedRole.filter(({role_id}) => role_id !== event.source.value);
        }
      }
```

This adds and remove data from array of objects. However, when the page loads/initiates the array of objects is empty (obviously).

What is the optimal way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: For me it is a little bit hard to follow your intension. I assume your data objects are received from any backend server? Have you tried to put the role and team selectors in any kind of generic list with ngFor?

Comment: Yes my data is from backend. Do you mean I shouldn't hardcode the checkboxes, instead get them from a table and ngFor? Then how do I match the user with the role they have? Sorry if I sound confusing.

Comment: Maybe you need to load also a list of all available roles and teams and loop over them with ngFor to create your selectors. Than set the checks for the single user based on its assignments locally, my checking/matching the role and team ids ... This would be my approach. Hope this sounds not to confusing...

Comment: So, I got my roles and teams table. Now I have my checkboxes displayed. How can I make them checked if the user has the role? and how to uncheck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very simple working example for your described behavior [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/U79vgdm1I7RwBQ3w?preview)

In your component's ts-file:

```
  constructor() {
    // get your roles and teams from server or locally coded
    this.roles = [{id:1, name: 'Role A'}, {id:2, name: 'Role B'}, {id:3, name: 'Role C'}];
    
    // get the user to display/edit
    this.user = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'User 1',
      roles: [1,2]
    };
  }

  isUserInRole(role: IRole):boolean{
    return this.user.roles.includes(role.id);
  }

  onRoleChange(role: IRole):void{
    var index = this.user.roles.indexOf(role.id, 0);
    if (index > -1) {
      this.user.roles.splice(index, 1);
    }else{
      this.user.roles.push(role.id);
    }
    console.log(this.user.roles);
  }
```

In your template something like this:

```
 <div *ngFor='let role of roles'>
    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isUserInRole(role)" (change)="onRoleChange(role)"/>{{role.name}}
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, I used your approach and changed it a little bit. I ended up u sing: return this.user.roles.some(e => e.role_id === role.role_id)

Comment: Your welcome. For sure, my given example is a very simple one. There are some refactorings usefull :)